# issue with for cycle Bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, for-loop

I have this bash code:

```
declare -a globalDir
#------------------------------#
#Code that fills globalDir array
#-----------------------------#

echo ${#globalDir[@]} #print globalDir lenght and I get 2


for element in $globalDir
do

    echo "$element"

done
```

My problem is that the code does not show any element of globalDir even if it's lenght is 2

Comment: Should be `for element in "${globalDir[@]}"`. Even then it should print at least the first element as it is. You sure you don't see any output and your array is populated?

Comment: Ok with for element in "${globalDir[@]}" it works. I have a dubt : for populate array I use this code                                                                        for folder in $allDirectory
do
if [[ "$folder" =~ ^$local ]]; then

    ((count++)) globalDir[$count]=$folder
fi
done                                                                                                                        Why in this case I use the for "for folder in $allDirectory" and not "for element in "${globalDir[@]}".

Comment: Right. You want increment `count` *after adding the value to the array. Remember indexes start from `0` in bash.

Comment: I edited previous comment